# How can i fix ( combine 1 audio and 1 image) with ffmpeg

Tags: c#, image, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have to create a video from an image and a wav file. the video must be of the length of the audio file.
I copied ffmpeg (static version) into the solution folder.
I also created an environment variable on windows.
I tried to start ffmpg with this code inserted in my c # program, but it does not work.
how can I fix it?

```
string immagine = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/" + nomeFile + ".jpg";
            bmp.Save(immagine);
            string video = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath + "/" + nomeFile + ".mp4";


            using (Process proc  = new Process()) 

            {
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe"; 
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " -loop 1 -i \"" + immagine + "\" -i \"" + suono + "\" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest " + video + " -y";
                proc.Start();

            }
```

Comment: _" it does not work"_ is not a useful problem statement. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to know what might be wrong. Depending on your _actual_ problem (which you haven't described), your question may not even be a programming question. For all we know, you just need help using ffmpeg, which would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the reply !Today i try to post the debug output. sorry for my english!

Comment: Does it work on the command line? If so then somehow you're probably not constructing the right command line...

Comment: in fact! I was wrong with the command line! I solved, thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Do what is most simple first ... on the command line issue this

```
ffmpeg -i myimage.jpg  -i  myaudio.wav   myout.mp4
```

to combine your photo and your audio file into an output video file ... you are not restricted to using those codec (jpg, wav, mp4, aac, ogg, etc.) so substitute at will ... after you have proven the syntax is correct only then put these parameters into your system call to ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks . I resolve!! I had made a stupid mistake. I made a mistake in the escape sequence!